# Next js with app directory build fails saying Export encountered errors on following paths:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js13

```html
const teams = [
 
];

const OurTeam = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <SecondaryHeroSection title="Our Team" />
      </div>
      <MainLayout>
        <section className="bg-whit">
          <div className="pb-8 px-4 mx-auto max-w-screen-xl lg:py-16 lg:px-6 ">
            <div className="mx-auto max-w-screen-sm text-center mb-8 lg:mb-16">
              <p className="font-light mt-10 sm:mt-0 text-gray-500  sm:text-xl dark:text-gray-400">
                Explore the profiles of our talented team members below and get
                to know the faces behind the expertise. Together, we are united
                by our common goal , and we are excited to embark on this journey with
                you.
              </p>
            </div>
            <div className="grid gap-8 grid-cols">
              {teams && teams?.map((member) => (
                <div
                  key={member?.id}
                  className="flex sm:flex-row flex-col  rounded-lg shadow w-full sm:h-[700px] overflow-hidden"
                >
                  <div className="w-full  ">
                    <Image
                      className="w-full  object-cover"
                      src={member?.img}
                      alt="Member Image"
                    />
                  </div>

                  <div className="p-5 w-fit">
                    <h3 className="text-xl font-bold tracking-tight text-tnt-primary">
                      <a href="#">{member?.name}</a>
                    </h3>
                    <span className="text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
                      {member?.position}
                    </span>
                    <p className="mt-3 mb-4 font-light text-gray-700">
                      {member?.desc}
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </MainLayout>
    </>
  );
};

export default OurTeam;
```

```html
import { FallbackLoader } from "@/components/loader/FallbackLoader";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const TeamList = dynamic(() => import("./Team"), { loading: FallbackLoader, ssr: true });

const Team =  () => {
  return <TeamList />;
};

export default Team;
```

and my folder structure is app/team/page.tsx which dynamically imports the Team component using next/dynamic.My folder structure is same through out the app. Everything is working fine when i run the app but unable to build the project. There is no any specific error shown in the terminal as well. [image]

Comment: can anyone help me with this?